# Vim compilation with Python 2.x support on mac

Tags: python, macos, vim

When I run `vim`, I get this error:

> YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with  Python 2.x
>   support

even though I compile vim with:

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-rubyinterp \
            --enable-pythoninterp \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-perlinterp \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr
```

according to [these instructions](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source). It looks like the compiled vim is placed in `/usr/bin/vim`, but I also tried my vim binaries in `/opt/local/bin/vim` and `/usr/bin/vi`, but I get the same error. What other options can make vim compile with Python2.x support?

**EDIT**

Here's the relevant output from `./configure`:

```
checking --enable-pythoninterp argument... yes
checking for python2... (cached) /usr/bin/python
checking Python version... (cached) 2.7
checking Python is 2.3 or better... yep
checking Python's install prefix... (cached) /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
checking Python's execution prefix... (cached) /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
(cached) checking Python's configuration directory... (cached) /usr/lib/python2.7/config
(cached) checking if -pthread should be used... no
checking if compile and link flags for Python are sane... no: PYTHON DISABLED
```

`ls /usr/lib/python2.7/config/` gives:

```
Makefile           Setup.local        install-sh         makesetup
Setup              config.c           libpython2.7.a     python.o
Setup.config       config.c.in        libpython2.7.dylib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running: `xcode-select --install`

This line in the `./config` output changed from `... no: PYTHON DISABLED` to
`checking if compile and link flags for Python are sane... yes`

Comment: This worked for me too. I wish I knew why it fixed it, but it'll do for now. Thanks Rose!

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work with Homebrew vim, the magical command is:

```
brew install vim --override-system-vim --HEAD
```

Hope this works for you, it took me some time before I stumbled upon this.

Comment: Tried, did not change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

What you pass to `./configure` is just a *wish* to have that feature. The *autoconf* rules will still test your system and only include the Python stuff if everything is available. To actually verify that Vim is built with Python support, you need to check the `:version` output for `+python`, or `:echo has('python')` needs to output `1`. If that's not the case, check the output of `./configure` for any Python-related stuff. You're probably missing some Python headers / libraries (but without your full `./configure` output, it's hard to tell).

Comment: You're right that the --version output shows `-python` rather than `+python`. How can I resolve my missing Python headers / libraries?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no Mac user, but [a search for the offending line](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22checking%20if%20compile%20and%20link%20flags%20for%20Python%20are%20sane...%20no%3A%20PYTHON%20DISABLED%22) yields some promising results...

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install MacVim: it's quick and painless.

The only valid reason for building Vim by hand on Mac OS X is if you need something that is not in MacVim (but still could make sense on a Mac) like lua scripting. If your needs are served by MacVim, why bother?

Comment: I tried. MacVim from MacPort does not have Python 2.x support.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MacPorts vim:

```
sudo port install vim +python27
```

This solved my problem. Founded [here](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32629)