# Compile vim with python 2.0 support

Tags: python, macos, vim

I follow the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303966/vim-compilation-with-python-2-x-support-on-mac) to compile Vim with Python 2.x support on Mac OS because I want the Vim plugin [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)

In configure it says:

```
checking for python2... (cached) /Users/t2wu/miniconda3/bin/python
checking Python version... (cached) 
checking Python is 2.3 or better...   File "<string>", line 1
    import sys; sys.exit( < 2.3)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
too old
```

It can't be too old. I wonder why it is checking out miniconda3 which has Python 3.3 installed (System `/usr/bin/python` is on version 2.7.5.) I've removed that directory from the PATH environmental variable from .bash_profile just because I want to compile this, but in general I want Python 3 to be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some alternatives. Personally, I installed Vim on Mac OS X using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). After downloading and installing graphically the `port` command, you can use the following from command line to install `vim` with support for Python 2.7:

```
$ sudo port install vim +python27
```

Notice that this also installs a Python 2.7 interpreter from MacPorts.

The advantage of this approach is that MacPorts will bring you updates to the Vim package, and you keep the system Python unmodified.

Comment: Wow superb! I didn't know about `+python27`.

Comment: Had I know this earlier I wouldn't have my system's original Vim overwritten. :/

Answer (score 0):

**YOU DON'T NEED TO DO ANY OF THAT.**

You only need to install [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) which comes with python support built-in. It will work out of the box if Python is correctly installed on your system.

Comment: I tried Macport's version of macvim and it didn't have Python support. Maybe it's because I was not using +python27 like logc said it with vim?

Comment: Download MacVim from the link in my question, that's all you need.

Comment: I downloaded MacVim from this link, and there wasn't python support.